# Do I have any recourse if I was pressured into a car lease?

Tags: california, auto-leasing

We thought our lease was due at the 3 year mark.  We contacted a dealer and the pressure sales was pushed strong.  In less than 2 days they found a car that was similar, but newer.

They stated that they would even look into buying our current car.  When looking into our current car they came back and stated that the numbers didn't work and they couldn't buy our car and suggested we go forth with the option they found.

Current lease was a Cadillac XT5, they were dropping the cost of what we were paying to put us into a 2023 XT4.  High pressure to sign and they would deliver the car.

Thinking we were doing the right thing and trusting them we signed at the end of 2 days and the car was delivered.   They took our old car back to the dealership.

When we woke the next morning and looked through the paperwork with fresh eyes we saw that our last lease was 39 months not 36.  The salesman on our deal actually looked up our car and knew that and did not bring it to our attention (we realized he did not have to) but pressured the sale through any way.  Do we have any recourse?

The ethics of this deal and dealership are clearly foul and in California there is no right of rescission for a lease so we are now stuck with double payment for the next 3 months.  Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Do you mean double payments for the next 3 months? I don't imagine there's any recourse just a costly lesson.

Comment: You still have to pay on the old car? So should you not have access to it? (I don’t know if you have use/space/desire for two cars, but just asking)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but you don't have any recourse.
It's very common for corporate salesmen to pressure you.
Obviously you cannot trust them, no matter how hard they push you.
Because they always push for their bonus, not for your well-being.